# How to use Netplan in Ubuntu 17.10 to add IP addresses for Wireless iface

Tags: 17.10, netplan

Being solely wifi connected, I successfully used the following 'etc/network/ifup.d' script in 16.04 to set up extra local IP addresses when my wireless interface came up. In 17.10 I'm being told to use Netplan. However, I'm finding little support for this kind of activity and wireless in general. Can anyone help with a simple Netplan YAML equivalent, please? My wireless interface is ID'd as wlan0 when it's up.

```
#!/bin/sh
# this script creates additional ip addresses using the wlan0 interface 
# for local server-based applications to be accessible from other local devices
if [ "$IFACE" != lo ]; then
    ip addr add 192.168.1.8/24 dev wlan0
    ip addr add 192.168.1.9/24 dev wlan0
fi
```

Comment: Please use the { } button above the edit window to format code, output, and error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find information on [configuring wireless interfaces](https://netplan.io/examples#wireless-interfaces) and [assigning multiple IP addresses](https://netplan.io/examples#multiple-addresses-on-an-interface) to the same interface at https://netplan.io .

Specifically something like the following is likely what you want (assuming you are using DHCP and adding static addresses, you don't really say)...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp2s0b1:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.8/24, 192.168.1.9/24]
      access-points:
        "network_ssid_name":
          password: "**********"
```

Comment: OK thanks everyone. I had in fact tried this (from the examples) however in debug mode it threw out a last line "definition wlan0 is not for us (backend 2)" which I took to be an error. In fact it had been working all along!