# How to set a static ip address on a local network using NetworkManager?

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, nmcli

### What I did

I am trying to create a wifi connection with a static ip using NetworkManager. Following are the steps of that process using the `nmcli` command.

Connection settings,

1. I created a new connection of type `wifi`.
2. I set *connection.id* to `StaticNet`
3. I set *connection.interface-name* to `wlp2s0`

IPV4 settings,

1. I set *ipv4.method* to `manual` (since I want it to be static)
2. I set *ipv4.addresses* to `192.168.1.10` (I checked with arp-scan
   and no connection is using that ip)
3. I set *ipv4.gateway* to `192.168.1.1`
4. I set *ipv4.dns* to `8.8.8.8.` (google's public dns server)

Now I tried to save but nmcli prompt doesn't let me unless I set *802-11-wireless.ssid*, so I set it to `wifi_ssid`, save and quit.

### How to proceed?

At this point `nmcli c` yields,

```
$ nmcli c
NAME       UUID                                  TYPE              DEVICE 
StaticNet  df1d3865-078b-4a94-877f-5ba460b68229  802-11-wireless   --
```

and `ip a` shows *state DOWN* for wifi. How can I proceed and complete the process (get connected to the local network using *StaticNet* connection)?

Comment: could it be as simple as `nmcli con up StaticNet` I wonder?

Comment: or setting the static IP address in the router (which is what I do successfully)

Comment: The activation is failing @steeldriver

Comment: That's a good idea as well @User24601 but I am just checking out some tutorials, I am following the instructor's directions but as you already know things don't work out in my case

Comment: If you want to do this in NM, why not just use the user interface? https://cloud.addictivetips.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/static-ip-feat.png The `/etc/network/interfaces` file is no longer valid after Ubuntu 16.04. I suggest that you revert your changes. If the name of your network is StaticNet, why did you tell nmcli that it is wifi_ssid? Finally doesn't this wireless network have a password? Didn't you specify it?

Comment: I think I lack some fundamental understanding on this @chili555. In case of wifi `connection.id` and  `802-11-wireless.ssid` should both set to `StaticNet`?

Comment: I believe that `connection.id` can be anything you wish, such as `home` or `work` or `library` however, the ssid must match the SSID, that is, the router name that you are trying to connect to. Don't forget the password!

Comment: Ok I need to ask a dumb question now, so if my home network is called *o21518* is that the SSID? @chili555 (if that's a *yes* I think you somehow answered my original question indirectly)

Comment: Yes, exactly. I believe it is safe to call both connection.id and 802-11-wireless.ssid o21518. Please be sure it is lower-case O and not capital O or zero 0. Check: `nmcli device wifi list` Please don't forget the password.

Comment: Thanks @chili555 I'll try that out. I think that's the reason why an ethernet connection works (because you don't need to specify a password since you're already connected through a cable).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109877/discussion-between-chili555-and-themelis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our chat, I recommended that the `connection.id` can probably be any name such as *home*, *work* or *library*. I also recommended that the `802-11-wireless.ssid` must be the name of the router, commonly referred to as the SSID. In order to make it easy to remember, there is no reason that both can't be named the same as the SSID.

I also reported that no wireless router will ever connect without the password and to make certain to specify it.

I also suggested this as a helpful answer:

[How to use Netplan in Ubuntu 17.10 to add IP addresses for Wireless iface](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025883/how-to-use-netplan-in-ubuntu-17-10-to-add-ip-addresses-for-wireless-iface)

Following this guidance, you connected properly.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use NetworkManager consider using the static ip address functionality of your network router.

Typically, log in to your router 192.168.1.1 (or as appropriate) and using your device MAC address, set the ip address you wish it to use (along with any other devices such as printers which would benefit from a fixed ip address).

Using this method, it will ensure that there are fewer risks of conflicts with other unrelated devices on the network (mobiles, tablets etc) connecting to the same router.

Comment: Yeah but I want to do it with `NetworkManager` :D

Comment: I did it also by editing the `/etc/network/interfaces`...

Comment: I suspect it is equally effective to go into the routers administration pages and check the DHCP pool. For example, if DHCP allows addresses in the range of 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.50, the set your static IP address outside the pool, for example, 192.168.1.100.